# I'm getting a 404 on my blog page after deploying to vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a blog in next.js and it's deployed to vercel.

I have a pages/[slug].tsx file

```
// pages/[slug].ts
import fs from "fs";
import { GetStaticPropsContext, InferGetStaticPropsType } from "next";
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote";
import Head from "next/head";

export default function PostPage({
  source,
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{source.frontmatter.title as string}</title>
      </Head>
      <MDXRemote
        {...source}
        // specifying the custom MDX components
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return { paths: [], fallback: "blocking" };
}

export async function getStaticProps(
  ctx: GetStaticPropsContext<{
    slug: string;
  }>
) {
  try {
    const { slug } = ctx.params!;

    // retrieve the MDX blog post file associated
    // with the specified slug parameter
    const postFile = fs.readFileSync(`_blogs/${slug}.mdx`);

    // read the MDX serialized content along with the frontmatter
    // from the .mdx blog post file
    const mdxSource = await serialize(postFile, { parseFrontmatter: true });
    return {
      props: {
        source: mdxSource,
      },
      // enable ISR
      revalidate: 60,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
}
```

In this I render a post that is a .mdx file from my _blogs folder. This works perfectly locally if there is a matching slug, however this doesn't work after deploying to vercel.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe '_blogs` directory is in gitignore so it is not deployed

Comment: where you able to solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue